# Problems to create Liferay project with netbeans 8

Tags: java, liferay, netbeans-8

i'm newbie about Liferay.

I starting to develop a simple Liferay plugin using Netbeans 8.0.2 but i have a problem. This is my steps:

1. I download Netbeans 8
2. I added A Portlet Support
3. I create project from Archetype (i selected liferay-archetype-portlet)
4. At the end i build the project and i have this error item

> The project com.mycompany:LiferayHelloWorld:1.0 
>   `(C:\progetti\java\LiferayHelloWorld\pom.xml)` has 5 errors
>       'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.liferay.portal:portal-
>   service:jar must be a valid version but is
>   '${liferay.version}'.
>
> @ line 55, column 13 'dependencies.dependency.version' for 
>   com.liferay.portal:util-bridges:jar must be a valid version but is
>   '${liferay.version}'.
>
> @ line 61, column 13 'dependencies.dependency.version' for >com.liferay.portal:util-taglib:jar must be a valid version but is
>   '${liferay.version}'.
>
> @ line 67, column 13 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.liferay.portal:util-java:jar must be a valid version but is
>   '${liferay.version}'.
>
> @ line 73, column 13 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for >com.liferay.maven.plugins:liferay-maven-plugin must be a valid version
>   but is '${liferay.maven.plugin.version}'.
>
> @ line 15, column 14

Somebody have an idea to solve it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `maven` you need to add a `dependencyManagement` section as shown in the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.4/maven-model/maven.html#class_dependencyManagement)

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your own variables values.
So, inside your pom.xml, as "project" children, add something like the following code (be aware that you need to insert values corresponding to your liferay installation, liferay version and liferay maven plugin version):

```
    <properties>
    <liferay.version>6.1.1</liferay.version>
    <liferay.auto.deploy.dir>/path/to/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/deploy</liferay.auto.deploy.dir>
    <liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir>/path/to/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/lib/ext</liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir>
    <liferay.app.server.portal.dir>/path/to/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/webapps/ROOT</liferay.app.server.portal.dir>
    <liferay.mvnplugin.version>6.2.0-ga1</liferay.mvnplugin.version>
</properties>
```

If you are not familiar with Maven, why you don't use [Liferay SDK](http://www.liferay.com/it/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/installing-the-sdk)? It uses Ant for building and deploying, so it can be easier for you.

Just a last note: why you don't use [Liferay IDE](https://www.liferay.com/it/downloads/liferay-projects/liferay-ide)? It is an Eclipse customization and help you both using SDK or Maven projects.